# Issue with InnoDB engine while enabling and [ skip-innodb ] - [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error

Tags: innodb, mysql5

In production server as of now we are running with MyIsam tables only, hence we have disabled the innodb engine with skip-innodb option. But now onwards we need to enable the innodb engine as well for creating few innodb tables. So we have commented the [ #skip-innodb ] option in my.cnf and restarted.  Please go through the below cases and request to provide any solution or tips for the same ?

Case 1: Disabled the innodb with skip-innodb option and "mysql>show engines" givens as below.

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB     | NO      | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

      Engine     | Support ...
    | InnoDB     | NO   ......
```

Case 2: As I want to enable the innodb, I commanded the #skip-innodb option and restarted. 
But now the show engines even not showing the InnoDB engine in the list. ?

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Mysql Version : 5.1.57-community-log 
OS : CentOS release 5.7 (Final)

Log:

```
120622 13:06:36  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
120622 13:06:36  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-creating-innodb.html
120622 13:06:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120622 13:06:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120622 13:06:36 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120622 13:06:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.57-community-log'  socket: '/data/mysqlsnd/mysql.sock1'  port: 3307  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS, MySQL version, startup errors or anything else you have tried.

Comment: I have updated the details ...

Answer (score 1):

Your log files could be corrupted.Try this :

1. Stop mysql.
2. Since you had no previous data in the innodb tables, remove (or move elsewhere) the log files, they should be named like `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0` and `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1` on default install.
3. Start mysql again

To show mysql innodb engine status type this

```
mysql> show engine innodb status;
```